# How can I align this navbar properly without using float?

Tags: html, css

Basically I want to make this...

[image: this line "Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces"]

... centered and aligned just like this:

[image: this code]

But, it seems like "float" is interfering on that. How would you fix that in a simple way so the first image looks like the second code?

```
<title>Product Page</title>

<style type="text/css">

    body{
        background: #eee;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }

    #header-img{
        float: left;
        width:18.5em;
        margin-top: 15px
        }
    .nav-link{
        position: relative;
        float:right;
        padding: 30px 45px 15px 20px;
    }

    #hero{
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: 120px; 
        margin-right: auto;
    }

</style>
```

```
<body>

    <header id="header">

     <img src="trombones.jpg" id="header-img">

     <nav id="nav-bar">

     <div class="nav-link">Pricing</div>
     <div class="nav-link">How It Works</div>
     <div class="nav-link">Features</div>

     </nav>

    </header>

    <div id="hero">
     <h2>Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</h2>
    </div> 

</body>
```

Comment: I'd move away from floats, which can be difficult to size well in a responsive world, to flexbox, which gives you a high level of control over sizing. Or just center-align it rather than floating.

Comment: Yeah, I will learn how to use that anyways. Thanks!

Comment: Dominick, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to understand what's expected of you from here. "Thank you" comments are discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the CSS of #hero to:

```
#hero {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And add 'overflow: hidden' css to correct the floats:

```
#header{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```